# Why is my driver only reading part of the string?

Tags: c++, string, kernel, driver

I'm attempting to read a string from a dummy program with a kernel driver. But only the first 4 char's are being read, I can't figure out why.

Part of the IOCTL code for reading the string:

```
else if (ControlCode = IO_READ_STRING_REQUEST)
{
    PREAD_REQUEST Values = (PREAD_REQUEST)buffer;
    PREAD_REQUEST ValuesOutput = (PREAD_REQUEST)buffer;
    PEPROCESS process;

    if (NT_SUCCESS(PsLookupProcessByProcessId(PID, &process)))
    {
        KeReadProcessMemory(process, Values->Address, &ValuesOutput->buffer, Values->Size);
        DbgPrint((PCSTR)Values->buffer);
        status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    }
    else
        status = STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;

    BytesIO = sizeof(READ_REQUEST);
}
```

This is the read struct:

```
typedef struct ReadStruct
{
    ULONGLONG Address;
    ULONGLONG Response;
    ULONGLONG Size;
    char buffer[128];

} READ_REQUEST, *PREAD_REQUEST;
```

The DbgPrint always prints stri when it's supposed to print stringChar, and stri is returned to the usermode.

This is how it's called from usermode:

```
void ReadString(std::string *string, DWORD64 address)
{
    ReadValues Values;
    std::memset(Values.buffer, '\0', 128);
    Values.Address = address;
    Values.Response = 0;    
    Values.Size = sizeof(128);

    if (!(DeviceIoControl(hDriver, IO_READ_STRING_REQUEST, &Values, sizeof(Values), &Values, sizeof(Values), 0, 0)))
    {
        std::cout << "RPM Failed!\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    *string = (std::string)Values.buffer;
}
```

The struct is the same:

```
struct ReadValues
{
    ULONGLONG Address;
    ULONGLONG Response;
    ULONGLONG Size;
    char buffer[128];
};
```

I thought it was the size, but when I specified the size to 11 (10 + \0) it also read only 4 chars.

Comment: `*string = (std::string)Values.buffer` -- If `Values.buffer` can contain null bytes, this assignment will not copy all of the bytes to `*string`.  What you want is to use the `std::string` constructor that takes a pointer and a size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
Values.Size = sizeof(128);
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is the same as `sizeof(int)` (which, I would guess, is `4` in your platform).

Either use `128` or `sizeof(buffer)` (the latter is arguably better since you won't be hard-coding the same constant in several places).